# How long the server manager will keep connection open to remote servers?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have groups and servers managed by Server Manager on Server 2012R2. I am just wondering that if Server Manager keeps the connection/Session open to managed servers all the time or it will only establish the connections whenever it checks the status of remote servers on a schedule? if so, how long the session will open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Manager relies on WinRM & DCOM, and has a refresh interval (can be set within Server Manager Propertes or Registry). I would assume this means it connects and then dies once it's done with its command-set.

I just tested it by manually refreshing a server and checking the `netstat` table before/during/after. The connection is Established over `5985` during the refresh, and closes once it's done. As to how long it remains open?... I suppose that depends on how long of a payload it has to execute.